# Can I use VB.net to write some tools for Qt-based application?

Tags: vb.net, qt

I want to make some tools for a messenger wrote on QT. I've just started reading on QT but still wondered if I can use VB.NET to write the tools (such as reading text , sending text to QT window). I only know VB.Net.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but it will be much harder than learning to use C++.

Comment: probably yes, through ActiveX: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-index.html